# Ajax function dosent go to the asmx function

Tags: javascript, ajax

after getting to the Ajax function CheckTherUser, from some reason it will no continue to the cs file CheckUsers1.
when I debbug it, I managae to get to the ajax function and after that it throwing me to the errorCB without an exeption massage

Js:

```js
 $(document).on('click', '#signin', function () {
            var user = document.getElementById("Usermail").value.toString();
            var password = document.getElementById("Userpass").value.toString();
            var req = {
                Id: user,
                Pass: password,
            }
            CheckTheUser(req, successCheckUserCB, errorCheckUserCB);

        });

        function successCheckUserCB(resutls) {
            resutls = $.parseJSON(resutls.d)
            localStorage.setItem("Userid", resutls.ClubMemberNumber);
            localStorage.setItem("Password1", resutls.Password);
        }

        function errorCheckUserCB(e) {
            alert(e.responseText);
        }

// Ajax function :

function CheckTheUser(req, successCheckUserCB, errorCheckUserCB) {

    // serialize the object to JSON string
    var dataString = JSON.stringify(req);

    $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
        url: 'SemWS.asmx/CheckUsers1',   // server side web service method
        data: dataString,                        // the parameters sent to the server
        type: 'POST',                              // can be also GET
        dataType: 'json',                          // expecting JSON datatype from the server
        contentType: 'application/json; charset = utf-8', // sent to the server
        success: successCheckUserCB,                // data.d id the Variable data contains the data we get from serverside
        error: errorCheckUserCB
    }) // end of ajax call
}
```

SemWS.cs:

```cs
 public string CheckUsers1(string Id, string Pass)
    {


        DBTools dbs = new DBTools();
        int x = dbs.ConfirmUser(Id, Pass);
        if (x == 1)
        {
            User us = new User();
            us.Email = Id;
            us.Password = Pass;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            // serialize to string
            string jsonString = js.Serialize(us);
            return jsonString;

        }
        else
            throw (new Exception("The ID or password are incorrect"));
    }
```

Comment: Does your CS code accept GET?  If so you could test your server code by visiting the ajax URL in a browser (with id and pass parameters set via querystring).  You should get the json response, if it's working.  Otherwise, use your browser devtools and look at the network request the ajax is generating, and its response.

Comment: "_without an exeption massage_" The error text is passed as the third parameter to the `error` handler: `errorCheckUserCB(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`